# Office UI Fabric - Button component post back after click

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-ui-fabric

I am creating a sample form using Office UI Fabric components, I can see button component rendered but when I click on the button I get page posted back.

I have a simple html button as well but that works fine.
Why post back happening with Fabric button only?

here is my code, I have added a content editor web part on my page and added this script init it. I have tried with visual web par as well but same result.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric- 
js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric- 
js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css" />
<script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui- 
fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>



<button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary AlertExample">
   <span class="ms-Button-label">Create Account</span> 
</button>

<input type="button" name="name" value="HTML button" onclick="htmlclcik()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var ButtonComponent = document.querySelector(".ms-Button.AlertExample");
new fabric["Button"](ButtonComponent, function () {
    alert("You clicked the Create Account button");
    return false;
});

function htmlclcik()
{
    alert("htmk click");
}
</script>
```

Update : This script is required to control this behavior.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
if (buttons && buttons.length) {
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i]) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () { return false; };
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding type to button element as given below:

```
<button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary AlertExample">
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Create Account</span> 
</button>
```